# Find the points closest to and farthest from the origin for a region in $\mathbb{R}^6$

Tags: regions, computational-geometry, homework, intersection

> Given $A$ being the intersection set between $x + y + z + u + v + w = 1$ and $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + u^2 + v^2 = 1$, find the closest and farthest points to the origin that belong to $A$ in the space $\mathbb{R}^6$.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Is this a question about the program Mathematica? If so, what have you tried thus far?

Comment: Yes, Wolfram Mathematica 11.3

Comment: Besides what Neumann proposed, nothing too relevant.

Comment: That being the case, this sort of question should first go to an instructor or TA for assistance in getting started. The scope of the forum starts, more or less, at the point where one presents actual code, along with specific questions about said code.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
NMinimize[{x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + u^2 + v^2 +w^2, {x + y + z + u + v + w == 1, x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + u^2 + v^2 == 1}}, {x, y, z, u, v, w}]
(*{1., {x -> -0.0316501, y -> -0.253188, z -> 0.544651, u -> 0.796892,v -> -0.0566812, w -> -0.0000230699}}*)
```

and

```
 NMaximize[{x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + u^2 + v^2 +w^2, {x + y + z + u + v + w == 1, x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + u^2 + v^2 == 1}}, {x, y, z, u, v, w}]
 (*{11.4721, {x -> -0.447214, y -> -0.447214, z -> -0.447214,u -> -0.447214, v -> -0.447214, w -> 3.23607}}*)
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea! Shouldn't we try to define the intersection "A" first? And is the result plottable in any way?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau - Thanks. I made a left turn in hyperspace and got lost. Deleted my comment.

Comment: @BobHanlon Right. It [ain't like dusting crops, boy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CcX8mDRIhYE)

Comment: @EichenH  `A` is defined by the two constraints, I think.